# Write a value to a form field - Value writes multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have written the script below to pull in data from a url string and then place in preexisting (un-editable) form fields.

```
<script>
var Month = getQueryVariable("Month");

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
var query = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
for (var vars = query.split("&"), i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]).replace("+", " ") == variable) {
        return decodeURIComponent(pair.slice(1).join("=")).replace("+", " ");
    }
}
return "NONE"
}

</script><script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('Month').readOnly = true;
</script>
```

I am able to pull in the data from the url just fine.  However I get an error when submitting, and upon inspecting the element, it appears the value that was passed has tripled!  Any idea what is causing this and how I can prevent it?  My assumption is it is something with the autotab.

```
<input id="Month" name="Month" class="month autotab autotabdate" type="text" value="12,12,12" size="2" maxlength="2" readonly="">
```

URL used is: https://test.com/welcome.html?Month=12

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the URL parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

Comment: What does your URL look like?

Comment: URL used is: https://test.com/welcome.html?Month=12

Comment: @sємsєм OP says that getting the value from the URL is working, so this is not a duplicate of _that_ question.

Comment: Sorry, I want to cancel this vote to close but I could not. @StephenP

Comment: The second script tag in your code should be placed at the end of the page before closing `</body>` then you have to supply the field with the value after making it readonly `document.getElementById('Month').value = Month;`

Comment: Thanks @sємsєм, followed your suggestion.  Still getting the same result where value="12,12,12" as opposed to just "12"

Comment: Got it... appears as if it was posting to https://test.com/welcome.html?Month=12.  Had to create another JavaScript tag to remove the section after html from the post action.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it... appears as if it was posting to test.com/welcome.html?Month=12. Had to create another JavaScript tag to remove the section after html from the post action.